# Is any way to get all participants of channel in telegram via telethon?

Tags: python, telethon, telegram-api

Is any way to get all participants of channel in telegram via telethon?
Attributes aggressive=True and limit= does not work now in client.get_participants() or client.iter_participants()

My code is below let me get only 200 participants in my channel:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
import pandas as pd
import asyncio

async def main():
    api_id = 12345678
    api_hash = 'xxx'
    phone = 'yyy'
    channel_href = 'zzz'

    client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)
    client = await client.start()
    dialogs = await client.get_dialogs()

    channels = {d.entity.username: d.entity
                for d in dialogs
                if d.is_channel}
    my_channel = channel_href.split('/')[-1]
    channel = channels[my_channel]

    members_telethon_list = await client.get_participants(channel, aggressive=True, limit=5660)

    username_list = [member.username for member in members_telethon_list]
    first_name_list = [member.first_name for member in members_telethon_list]
    last_name_list = [member.last_name for member in members_telethon_list]
    phone_list = [member.phone for member in members_telethon_list]

    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['username'] = username_list
    df['first_name'] = first_name_list
    df['last_name'] = last_name_list
    df['phone'] = phone_list
    df.to_csv('subscribers.csv', index=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Yes, I know get_event_loop is deprecated)
Thanks for answers!

Comment: No, the Telegram server intentionally limits how many members can be fetched to prevent spam, and this cannot be bypassed.

Comment: Thanks, but I really would prefer if exclusively my nickname was used online.